# Firebase remove strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, firebase

i have the following code in my app

```
this.obsRef.remove(function(error) {
      self.firebaseRef.child('users/'+self.user.name+'/invite')
               .remove(function(error) {
                    self.enterLobby();
                });
            });
```

What is code should do is to remove obsRef from firebase and then remove
the location on 'users/$user/invite'. Once all is removed enterLobby
is called.

Now the problem is on enterLobby() i got this following code:

```
this.userListRef.child(this.user.name).child('invite')
             .on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
           console.log("INVITE");
        });
```

And the code inside enterLobby() is executed every time.
I'm missing something or the callback for .remove() doesn't work as supposed?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The `.on('child_added')` handler will make sure the provided callback is called every time a child is added. This is why you are seeing the code execute multiple times. You may want to use `.once('value')` instead:

```js
this.userListRef.child(this.user.name).child('invite').
  once('value', function(snapshot) { console.log("INVITE"); });
```

Comment: I need the .on() cause multiple children can be added. The problem is that before calling enterLobby() call several times to be sure this.userListRef.child(this.user.name).child('invite').off().

Comment: What is triggering the remove? Each remove callback will be called only once, so if the remove itself is being triggered multiple times, enterLobby() will be called as well.